# Read a column from a table which its id is another table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Probably I dont ask the title well.

I have three tables as shown in the figure.

I want to get the column `x` in table `C` where `wid` is in table `B`. Some of the `wid` in table `C` is not needed, I want only `wid`s that their `mid` in table `B` are in table `A.`

Can you help me to solve this?

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Joining tables on primary key = other table's foreign key. There are inner/outer left and equi joins. Read on it.

```
select A.Mid, C.X
from A
left join B on B.Mid = A.Mid
join C on C.Wid = B.Wid
```